# Does cnosdb support timing execution of sql and sending query results?

Tags: cnosdb

According to the official documentation, the Enterprise Edition can synchronize written data to multiple nodes through the subscription function. May I ask whether cnosdb supports timing execution of sql and sending query results. It doesn't look like this is much different in implementation from the subscription functionality.